# Does the Champion do anything?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

[The wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Soldier#Champion) is quite unclear on the Champion. From what I gather he might "boost the morale". Is there a point to appointing one?

> The champion is a noble position appointed by the Baron (that is, you can appoint it, but you can't do so without a baron or greater noble being present). A champion has no special room requirements, but may make a single demand eventually. As the title of champion is bestowed by appointment rather than merit, you may want to have your best teacher be the champion and conduct weapon demonstrations to boost the morale of training soldiers while your toughest killers go out and fight goblins.

Comment: I wonder if he might lessen the effects of unhappiness from long stretches of being on duty.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but I think a champion will give positive thoughts to nearby/interacting soldiers (Or maybe all dwarves). See if any new interesting thoughts pop up after you appoint one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Champion can trigger the *pillar of society* thought in dwarves they interact with. Depending on that dwarf's *liberalism* personality trait (how much they admire tradition), this can be an unhappy or a happy thought (ranging from -5 to +20 happiness).

This thought can be triggered by other nobles too, so the Champion has no unique ability.

Given the possible happiness modifiers from this thought, it is more likely to do good than bad, so leaving the Champion out of the military to interact at parties is reasonable.